# Why is "aur-" the future stem of "avoir", instead of "avr-"?

Tags: étymologie

In many Romance languages the future tense is conjugated with the infinitive stem + combining present of "to have".

For example:

- ES *haber* → *habr-* + *hé* = *habré*
- IT *avere* → *avr-* + *ho* = *avrò*

But the stem in French is *a**u**r-*, not *a**v**r-*.

I'm aware that the letter V used to pronounce the same way as U is nowadays, but why isn't the letter V retained in the future stem of *avoir*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any clear explanation for why modern French doesn't use  *avr-* as the future/conditional stem of *avoir.* *Savoir* shows the same AV/AU alternation. In contrast, we do see *-vr-* in the future/conditional stems of a number of *-evoir* verbs, such as *devoir* and *recevoir.*

> The forms [so] and [o] which replace the future/conditional roots of the French verbs *savoir* 'to know' and *avoir* 'to have' (*savra/avra, savroit/avroit* > *saura/aura, saurait/aurait*) are of unexplained origin (see Maiden 1992). Possibly they reflect a sporadic or dialectal sound change...

("[Morphological Innovation](https://books.google.com/books?id=sE-N3v0IoXcC&pg=PA265)", by Martin Maiden, in *The Cambridge History of the Romance Languages, Volume 1* (2011), p. 265)

Something I found out that may be related in some way: the verb *boire* seems to have lost *-v-* not only in its future/conditional stem but also in its infinitive form. Wiktionary says that in Old French, we can see the infinitive form *boivre* and the future/conditional stem *bevr-.*

Comment: Worth considering that while this kind of evolution of /C(V)L/ clusters is known in Walloon (STABULUM < */stab.lo/ < */staw.lə/ < wal. ståle /stɔːl/; DIABOLUM < */djab.lo/ < */djaw.lə/ < wal. diåle /dʒɔːl ~ dʒɑːl/; MACRUM < */mag.ro/ < */m(w)aj.rə/ < wal. m(w)aire /m(w)e:r/), saur- and aur- are kind of exceptional in being generalised to almost every Romance variety in France, Belgium and Switzerland (the South-West has forms like /sabɛr-/ for saur-, but /aʊ̞r-/ for aur-)

Comment: see ALF maps 97, 98, 99 and 1202  http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect3/carteTheme